# Is there a way for sorting numbers with leading zeros like strings otherwise like numbers?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sorting, locale, icu

I have a collation for natural sorting strings (provider = icu, locale = 'en-u-kn-true') in postgres 14.1 database. NodeJS v12.16.1. When strings have non-zero leading numbers like 1 2 11 22, sortation is working fine for me. If the numbers start with zero, I get the correct order in terms of numbers [000, 00, 0, 001, 01, 1, 002, 02, 2], but in this case I expect an order like [000, 001, 002, 00, 01, 02, 0, 1, 2]. Is there any way to get this behavior using additional settings for locale or some other way.  The main thing is that it should work fast (up to 2-3 seconds), for about one million records.

Comment: Can you define the desired ordering exactly, that is, with general rules rather than with an example? If not, it is hard to answer. If yes, you are already close to the answer.

Comment: Order should be [ 000, 001, 002, 00, 01, 02, 0, 1, 2, 10, 200, 201 ]. Numbers with zeros in front go first. The number of zeros also affects the order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort by the nomber of leading zeros, then by the numeric value:

```
ORDER BY
   length(col)
      - length(trim(LEADING '0' FROM col))
      DESC,
   col COLLATE natural_coll
```